# Creating condition statement with ANTLR 4 and Java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, antlr4

So I'm trying to build myself my own programming language with swedish syntax(most for fun) and I have successfully managed to create variables and do some basic arithmetic on them. Moving on to do some conditional statements, I ran into some trouble. To start off, here is my (relevant) code:

*SPL.g4   //My grammar file.*

```
grammar SPL;

file
:code
;

code
:statement ';' code
;

statement
:print
|assign
|decl
|loop
|condition
;


//Declares variable
decl
:'variabel' ID
;

//Assign variable with an expression.
assign
:ID '=' expr
;

//A general expression.
expr
 :'-' expr                              #unaryMinusExpr
 |'!' expr                              #notExpr
 |expr op=('/' | '*') expr              #multiplicationExpr
 |expr op=('+' | '-') expr              #additiveExpr
 |expr op=('<=' |'>=' | '<' | '>') expr #relationalExpr
 |expr op=('=' | '!=') expr             #equalityExpr
 |expr 'OCH' expr                       #andExpr
 |expr 'ELLER' expr                     #orExpr
 |atomExpr                              #atom
 ;

//An atomic expression, more or less just a variable.
atomExpr
:ID
|INT
|'(' expr ')'
;

ID:('a'..'z')+ ;
STR:([a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*)+ ;
INT:([0-9]+)+ ;
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip ;

//Prints expr to the console
print
: 'skriv' expr
;

//Supposed to be some kind of loop and condition WORK IN PROGRESS!

condition
:'om' conditionCode ('annars om'  conditionCode)* ('annars' otherBlock)?
;

conditionCode
 : expr otherBlock
 ;

otherBlock
 :'{'file'}'
 | code
 ;


 loop
 :'när' expr ';'
 ;
```

*Interpreter*

```
import grammar.SPLBaseListener;
import grammar.SPLParser;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Interpretes the code genereated by the parser.
 * Overrides methods from the TestBaseListener so we can decide what happends.
 * Created by student on 2017-01-27.
 *
 */

public class Interpreter extends SPLBaseListener {

/**
 * A class that holds a value. Used for storing key & value pairs in a hashmap.
 */
private static class Variable {
    int val;

    public Variable(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

private final HashMap<String, Variable> vars = new HashMap<>(); //Stores keys and values.
private Stack<Integer> exprVal = new Stack<>(); //Stores the current values.
private Stack<Boolean> conditionBooleans = new Stack<>(); //Stores the evaluated conditions


/**
 * Returns a variable from the hashmap given the variable's name.
 *
 * @param tok
 * @return
 */
private Variable getVar(Token tok) {
    String name = tok.getText();
    Variable v = vars.get(name);
    if (v == null) {
        error(tok.getLine(), "undefined " + name);
        return new Variable(0);   // avoid null pointer exception
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}

/**
 * When entering a declaration of a variable, we put it in the hashtable with it's name
 * and a initial value of 0.
 *
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override
public void enterDecl(SPLParser.DeclContext ctx) {
    String name = ctx.ID().getText();
    Variable old = vars.put(name, new Variable(0));
    if (old != null) {
        error(ctx.ID().getSymbol().getLine(), "redefined " + name);
    }
}

/**
 * When we have exited the assignment, the variable already stored, get's the
 * value that the stack is holdning.
 *
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override
public void exitAssign(SPLParser.AssignContext ctx) {
    getVar(ctx.ID().getSymbol()).val = exprVal.pop();
}

/**
 * If + add two numbers top of stack else substract them and add them back.
 *
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override public void exitAdditiveExpr(SPLParser.AdditiveExprContext ctx) {
    String op = ctx.op.getText();
    if(op.equals("+")){
        exprVal.push(exprVal.pop() + exprVal.pop());
    }else{ // '-'
        int top = (exprVal.pop());
        int second = (exprVal.pop());
        exprVal.push(second - top);
    }
}

/**
 * If * multiplty two numbers top of stack else divide them and add them back.
 *
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override public void exitMultiplicationExpr(SPLParser.MultiplicationExprContext ctx) {
    String op = ctx.op.getText();
    if(op.equals("*")){
        exprVal.push(exprVal.pop() * exprVal.pop());
    }else{// '/'
        int top = (exprVal.pop());
        int second = (exprVal.pop());
        exprVal.push(second / top);
    }
}

/**
 * Takes the two top elements from the stack and compares them.
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override public void exitRelationalExpr(SPLParser.RelationalExprContext ctx) {

    System.out.println("Im here checking relation! " + exprVal.size());
    int top = (exprVal.pop());
    int second = (exprVal.pop());

    switch (ctx.op.getText()) {
        case "<=":
            System.out.println("<=");
            if(top<=second)
                conditionBooleans.push(true);
            break;
        case ">=":
            System.out.println(">=");
            if(top>=second)
                conditionBooleans.push(true);
            break;
        case "<":
            System.out.println("<");
            if(top<second)
                conditionBooleans.push(true);
            break;
        case ">":
            System.out.println(">");
            if(top>second)
                conditionBooleans.push(true);
            break;
        default:
            conditionBooleans.push(false);
    }
}


/**
 * Decides what codeblock to run. TODO DOES NOT WORK!
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override public void enterCondition(SPLParser.ConditionContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("\n CONDITION ENTERED------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(ctx.conditionCode().get(0).getText());

}

/**
 * When a atomexpression is declared in code
 * and if it's not null it will be pushed onto the stack.
 *
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override
public void enterAtomExpr(SPLParser.AtomExprContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.ID() != null) {
        exprVal.push(getVar(ctx.ID().getSymbol()).val);
    } else if (ctx.INT() != null) {
        exprVal.push(Integer.parseInt(ctx.INT().getText()));
    }
}

/**
 * Prints the value of exprValue.
 *
 * @param ctx
 */
@Override
public void exitPrint(SPLParser.PrintContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("Utskrift:");
    System.out.println(exprVal.pop());//Pop off the top value and print it.
}

/**
 * Prints error message to the console.
 *
 * @param line
 * @param msg
 */
private void error(int line, String msg) {
    System.err.println(":" + line + ": " + msg);
}
}
```

*test.t   //the test file I'm using*

```
variabel a;
variabel b;

a = 10;
b = 20;

a = a + b;

om a < b{
   skriv a;
};
```

So when the interpreter reaches the if statement, that is first getting evaluated, and then it goes on to evaluate the expression. I am not sure of the order here and what to do. I believe I should save the value of the condition so I can retrieve it later on and decide on which codeblock to run. But I'm totaly lost on where to even begin.

Comment: Here is a small toy language that shows how you could handle `if` statements in an ANTLR4 visitor: https://github.com/bkiers/Mu

Comment: A yes, I have already checked that one out, great examples! But what if I don't want to use the visitor pattern?

Comment: A visitor isn't much different than a listener.

Comment: I'm gonna try using visitor instead, it seems pretty straight forward.